# Mongoose sends existing document when validation failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, express, mongoose

I have a POST request to create a document. My problem is that mongoose sets the original document as part of the response when validation fails. I would like to make mongoose not send existing document, well mainly the hashed password.

This is the response

```
{
"code": 11000,
"index": 0,
"errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: ole.tournament index: name_1 dup key: { : \"First tournament\" }",
"op": {
    "name": "First tournament",
    "tournType": "single elimination",
    "seriesType": "bo1",
    "password": "$2a$10$xhA5UkpK.xH4QROdHf/Os.djs9CcU3C8PPcM8j99RocYPHS3x0tIC",
    "_creator": "5992734ebaa773270898e248",
    "_id": "59927361baa773270898e24a",
    "participants": [],
    "startedDate": null,
    "createdDate": "2017-08-15T04:06:57.640Z",
    "__v": 0
}
}
```

This is some code I've added so mongoose doesn't send the password, but it only works when creating or updating a document, but not when path validation fails:

```
TournamentSchema.methods.toJSON = function(){
  var tournament = this;
  var tournamentObject = tournament.toObject();
  return _.omit(tournamentObject, "password");
}
```

This is my route

```
.post('/add', authenticate, (req, res) => {
  req.body._creator = req.user._id;
  tournament = new Tournament(req.body);
  tournament.save().then((tournDoc) =>{
    res.status(200).send(tournDoc);
  }).catch((e) => {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  })
})
```

I know a quick way to fix this is by omitting it in the catch block, but is there a mongoose way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: you can always manipulate the response that you are sending, create a whitelist object.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to send back only the `errmsg` ie error message to the client. It is not a good practice to send full error object to the client. You can look at the below code:

```
.post('/add', authenticate, (req, res) => {
   req.body._creator = req.user._id;
   tournament = new Tournament(req.body);
   tournament.save().then((tournDoc) =>{
      res.status(200).send(tournDoc);
   }).catch((e) => {
      res.status(400).send(e.errmsg);
   })
})
```

Or you can even send you custom error message to the client like below:

```
.post('/add', authenticate, (req, res) => {
   req.body._creator = req.user._id;
   tournament = new Tournament(req.body);
   tournament.save().then((tournDoc) =>{
      res.status(200).send(tournDoc);
   }).catch((e) => {
      if(e.code == 11000) {
         res.status(409).send("Validation failed!!");
      }
      res.status(500).send("Error occurred!! Please try again.");
   })
})
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I figured I had to do. I though there would be an option to avoid this mongoose's behavior. Thank you.